# SQL Server Management Studio is filling columns with spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to manage my database.

The problem is that if I have a `nchar(50)` column in a table and I insert a value of `test`, what I will find in my table is this value

```
test<46spaces>
```

These spaces are making so much trouble for me. How can I stop this strange action?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is you're using char / nchar which are fixed length strings. Change your datatype to nvarchar.

Comment: Thank you, it was that simple! :p